# Android Studio Error in connect to asp.net API

Tags: android, asp.net, android-volley

i trying to connect my project in android studio to Asp.net API 
and i'm using Volley Lib to Get Json Request but he did'nt read the response 
and I getting this massage in Log 
((( E/Volley: [352] BasicNetwork.performRequest:
 Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.10.4.150:61511/api/Feedback/30)))
-Api work correctly i`m test with postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoI0o.jpg)

```
public static final String GET_BY_ID = "http://10.10.4.150:61511/api/Feedback/30";

EditText id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idtxt);
}
public void click(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnget) {
        insertData (id.getText().toString()) ;
    }

}
public void  insertData (String value){
    HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
    param.put("id",value);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_BY_ID,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject ob = response.getJSONObject("userId")    ;
                int name = ob.getInt("userId");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
            return headers;
        }};

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

}

Comment: my post man test   https://ibb.co/fCW4aq

Comment: Your phone's Wifi and Computer's Wifi must be the same. Also, Make sure you've added internet connection permission. And, Did you put header in postman?

Comment: -i add the internet permission in the project                                                            -i but  Parameter in Postman Headers http://localhost:61511/api/Feedback/parameter

Comment: Are these headers correct; `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");`

Comment: How can I verify this

Comment: In postman, there is a column called "header" right.. Can you post a pic of that please..

Comment: https://ibb.co/ioJpQq

Comment: Remove this line: `headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");` from your code and try. If same error comes write like this: `headers.put("User-Agent", "My useragent");`

Comment: i try replace toheaders.put("User-Agent", "My useragent");                                                 and try to remove it                                                                                                       get same error [401] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.10.4.150:61511/api/Feedback/30                                       
          :(